# Eclipse formatter align fields in columns

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

I'm trying to use the Eclipse formatter (but not Eclipse), and I'm trying to use "align fields in columns".  This has side effects I don't like:

```
class Thing {
    int    x       = 0;                       // comment is pushed aside
    double trouble = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
}
```

If `trouble` had been an anonymous class or a 2d array, it would have been even worse.  Can the comment being pushed aside be stopped somehow?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Which side effect do you not like?

Comment: I agree with Chetan; when you say "Can this be stopped", what is it exactly that you want to be stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a valid point, and I couldn't find a way to prevent Eclipse aligning the comments when using *"Align fields in columns"*.

Even if you set *"Preserve white space between code and line comments"* on the **Comments** tab the line comments still get aligned.

I raised a bug with Eclipse for this:

[Bug 532970 - Eclipse formatter formatting single line comment incorrectly](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532970)

Hopefully they will see it as a bug rather than a feature.

Comment: Wow, you actually filed a bug report.  Um, thank you!

Comment: @MarkVY FYI, the bug I raised for this issue was marked as a duplicate of existing [Eclipse Bug 373625](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373625) which has just been closed with a status of RESOLVED FIXED. The fix should be available soon in Eclipse Release 4.8. (The current Release is 4.7.3a.)

Comment: Wow, this is great news.   Thanks!

Comment: @MarkVY The issue you raised has been fixed in Eclipse 4.8 (Photon Release). I just tested and comment formatting seems to work properly now. Update your post if the formatting problem persists for you under Photon.

Comment: LOVELY.  Can't try this now, but will hopefully remember to report back when I do.